# How to remove lines based on duplicated value in a specific field?

Tags: shell, sorting

For example, I have this chromosome file:

```
Chr1  0   145   Region1
Chr1  450  500  Region2
Chr1  499  549  Region2
...
```

I'd like to remove the third line because Region2 appeared on line 2. I would greatly appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got a tab delimiter, this should work using awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '!x[$4]++' file.txt
```

If its not tab, just change '\t' to whatever the delimiter is, as by default awk assumes space.

Here's an example showing the results:

input:

```
~$ cat file.txt
Chr1    0       145     Region1
Chr1    450     500     Region2
Chr1    499     549     Region2
```

awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '!x[$4]++' file.txt
Chr1    0       145     Region1
Chr1    450     500     Region2
```

This works by printing when an element is added to the array that has not been encountered before.  It's a pretty standard deduping one-liner just modified to care about a specific field and not the whole line.

It works by adding the 4th field to an associative array and post increments it, so it returns 0 the first time it's added and increments with each subsequent duplicate item in the array. Adding in the ! to reverse this logic, we'll print if the post increment is 0, and not if its anything else, which it will be with each subsequent duplicate addition.

For example, adding a few more lines to the file:

```
~$ cat file.txt
Chr1    0       145     Region1
Chr1    450     500     Region2
Chr1    499     549     Region2
Chr1    499     555     Region2
Chr1    499     555     Region3
Chr1    499     556     Region3
```

And then changing our print to show the output we're testing:

```
~$ awk -F'\t' '{print x[$4]++}' file.txt
0
0
1
2
0
1
```

It should be much more obvious what is happening here.